# Getting 401 Unauthorized - CORS origin error while posting using HttpClient in Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, angular5, angular-httpclient

Getting the below error while attempting to post data into my backend firebase DB.

Please find the code snippets below:

```
storeUsers(users: any[]){
        return this.http.post('https://promise-90488.firebaseio.com/data.json', users);
    }
```

appcomponent.ts:

```
const result = Object.assign({}, this.userForm.value );
console.log(result);
this.userService.storeUsers(result)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
```

And the error messages are below:

> POST https://promise-90488.firebaseio.com/data.json 401 (Unauthorized)
>   app.component.ts:37  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status:
>   401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url:
>   "https://promise-90488.firebaseio.com/data.json", ok: false, …} error:
>   {error: "Permission denied"} headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames:
>   Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message: "Http failure response
>   for https://promise-90488.firebaseio.com/data.json: 401 Unauthorized"
>   name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 401 statusText:
>   "Unauthorized" url: "https://promise-90488.firebaseio.com/data.json"
>   **proto**: HttpResponseBase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: I am not sure where you got the CORS error from, the error message shows `401`, which is related to authorization.  From Another Thread:  `"Receiving a 403 response is the server telling you, “I’m sorry. I know who you are–I believe who you say you are–but you just don’t have permission to access this resource. Maybe if you ask the system administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please don’t bother me again until your predicament changes.”`

Comment: CORS is a BE error, not a Front-end one. Post the relevan BE stuff please.

Comment: `this.http.post` is going to make a cross-origin JSON formatted POST request, that requires a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, if that gets a 401 response then the CORS request will fail because the browser hasn't been given permission to make the POST request.

Comment: Why do you say this is a CORS problem? I don't see any mention to that in your post apart from title

Comment: … ditto 405 responses.

Comment: It may not be a CORS one but can you help in fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're not passing the authorization header with the request

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

return this.http.post('https://promise-90488.firebaseio.com/data.json', users, httpOptions);
```

Check the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) for more detail

To include authorization headers with all requests you can implement an interceptor to do that:

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Get the auth token from the service.
    const authToken = this.auth.getAuthorizationToken();

    // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
    // cloned headers, updated with the authorization.
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
    });

    // send cloned request with header to the next handler.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

You can read more about interceptors [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Comment: Still Getting the same problem

Comment: What type of authorization are you using? is it bearer token?